# path instruction in Python

Tags: command-line, python3

I'm completely new to Ubuntu/Linux and to Python. I'm reading a book called: Python for Data Analysis. On the first example they read a .txt file (which I have in my folder Documents/Books/ch02) using the next lines inside IPYTHON:

```
In [15]: path = 'ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
In [16]: open(path).readline()
```

so...how could I specify my directory where I have that specific file on the first line? I have tried

```
path = 'Documents/Books/ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt'
```

but it doesn't work...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you have will work if your python program is in the directory that has Documents in it.  Your best bet would be to fully qualify the directory with something like

```
path= '/home/{myuser}/Documents/Books/ch02/usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.tx'
```

Of course, the `{myuser}` should be your user id.  Also, be aware that linux is case sensitive. BTW, entering `pwd` at your command prompt will give you the current directory in case you don't know it.